# Gradle task dependency on subproject

Tags: kotlin, gradle

Is there a way to have gradle task depend on the code in one of the sub projects? Let's say I have project structure like so:

```
app/
  buid.gradle
  ...
myScripts/
  buid.gradle
  ...
settings.gradle
gradlew
```

I want to add a custom task to build.gradle.kts in myScripts project, which will depend on the classes defined in the app project. Is there a way to do this? My understanding is that because it's a different gradle project this shouldn't add circular dependency, so this should be possible in theory?

For context, I want to add a gradle task that would automatically generate .sql migration files based on the defined JPA entities. In order to do it, I need to load these entity classes and inspect them with reflection, and I can't seem to make them available within the build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly it is possible. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) is Gradle's word on the subject.

I suggest the way you go about it is:

1. Create a new [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html) which holds the dependencies needed for your new task in the `myScripts` project:

```
configurations {
    register("myConfiguration")
}
```

2. Add a dependency on the `app` sub-project to that configuration:

```
dependencies {
    add("myConfiguration", project(":app"))
}
```

The new configuration will then contain the artifacts from the `app` project (presumably including the JAR containing the `.class` files you are after).

3. You can then use it as an [input](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) for your new task (`Configuration` extends `FileCollection`) defined in a separate class:

```
open class MyTask : DefaultTask() {
    @InputFiles
    lateinit var fileInputs: FileCollection

    @TaskAction
    fun doSomething() {
        // task code
    }
}
```

4. And you must of course also register and configure the task:

```
tasks.register<MyTask>("myTask") {
   fileInputs = configurations.getByName("myConfiguration")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With this you're only able to get the jar files, which you can later read but it's not as straightforward as using reflection to find all available classes.

Isn't there a way to do it so that all of these classes are loaded and are available within the gradle script?

Comment: I believe this is the standard way of sharing any outputs between subprojects. Are you saying that you want to run the output code from the app project in the *build* code of the myScripts project? I don't think that's possible because of project evaluation order. You'd need to separate the projects and load the app project in as a dependency from some kind of repository.

Comment: Another approach is to run a task which starts a JVM application in the myScripts project (using the application plugin and a "main" method) which does the processing you need. If you do that, you can put dependencies.implementation(project(":app")) in the myScripts build.gradle.kts file and the code from the app project will be available in myScripts code.